# jQuery Ajax file upload : Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

**BACKGROUND**

I'm building a Spring MVC web application on Java8 and running it on tomcat8. In addition to this info, Spring version is `4.1.6.RELEASE` and `Servlet 3.1` I'm giving you the environmental background, because some problem solvers mentioned the version is related to this error.

**MY CODE**

Below is the `root-context.xml`

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">          
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20000000" />
</bean>
```

Below is my `FileController`

```
@Controller
public class FileController { 
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileController.class);

    private static final String UploadFolder = "Files";

    @RequestMapping("/uploadFile")
    @ResponseBody
    public void uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {     
        String fileName = "";
        PrintWriter script = response.getWriter();

        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

                fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(file.getOriginalFilename());

                String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);



                String base = System.getProperty("catalina.home");

                File dir = new File(base + File.separator + UploadFolder);                

                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }

                Date date = new Date();
                String year = DateTimeUtility.getInstance().getYear(date);
                String month = DateTimeUtility.getInstance().getMonth(date);
                String uniqueFileName = DateTimeUtility.getInstance().getDateTime(date);

                File dateDir = new File(base + File.separator + UploadFolder + File.separator + year + File.separator + month);

                if (!dateDir.exists()) {
                    dateDir.mkdirs();
                }

                File uploadedFile = new File(dateDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + uniqueFileName + WordCollections.UNDERBAR +  fileName);

                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(uploadedFile));

                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();

                logger.info("Server File Location = " + uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());                  
                script.write("Uploading file was successful");
            } catch (Exception e) {             
                logger.error("Server failed to upload this file : " + fileName);
                script.write("Uploading file was failed");
            }
        } else {
            logger.error("The requested file is empty");
            script.write("Uploading file was empty");
        }
    }
```

Below is my form

```
<form id="upload" method="POST" action="/uploadFile.json" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        File to upload: <input type="file" name="file" onchange="MyScript.uploadFile(this);"><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
    </form>
```

**STRANGE THING**

is that uploading files through `form submit` has no problem. It works like a charm !! I have nothing to complain for `form submit` !!

**BUT THIS AJAX BELOW DOESN'T WORK**

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/uploadFile",
                data: {name: "file", file: inputElement.files[0]},
                contentType: 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary0XBBar2mAFEE8zbv',
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                /*beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p");
                    settings.data = {name: "file", file: inputElement.files[0]};                    
                },*/
                success: function (result) {                        
                    if ( result.reseponseInfo == "SUCCESS" ) {

                    } else {

                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    console.log(result.responseText);
                }
            });
```

When I'm trying to upload file with above ajax call, server throws me this error.

```
2015-04-07 18:37:30 DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing POST request for [/uploadFile]
2015-04-07 18:37:30 DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /uploadFile
2015-04-07 18:37:30 DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public void com.company.web.controller.FileController.uploadFile(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException]
2015-04-07 18:37:30 DEBUG: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'fileController'
2015-04-07 18:37:30 DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void com.company.web.controller.FileController.uploadFile(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present
2015-04-07 18:37:30 DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void com.company.web.controller.FileController.uploadFile(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present
2015-04-07 18:37:30 DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public void com.company.web.controller.FileController.uploadFile(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present
2015-04-07 18:37:30 DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2015-04-07 18:37:30 DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

And browser says something like...

```
<body><h1>HTTP Status 400 - Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present</h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.20</h3></body></html>
```

The point is **Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present** and **400 Bad Request**.

I've googled with this keyword and searched as much as I could, like I always do before posting a question on `stackoverflow`

I really don't get it why only `ajax` doesn't work here!! when submit upload works just fine.

Comment: You are using action="/uploadFile.json". Is this file already present ?

Comment: Make sure the `inputElement.files[0]` isn't null

Comment: @Turtle It's not null for sure.

Comment: @RohitBandooni the prefix doesn't matter. I changed it and tried already.

Comment: Did you try making action="#" as you are already specifying the url in your javascript code. Also, try using preventDefault() before $.ajax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a try like this:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append( "file", $("input[name=file]").files[0]);

 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/uploadFile",
                data: fd,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                /*beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p");
                    settings.data = {name: "file", file: inputElement.files[0]};                    
                },*/
                success: function (result) {                        
                    if ( result.reseponseInfo == "SUCCESS" ) {

                    } else {

                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    console.log(result.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hey !! It works like a charm ~! setting `contentType : false` on ajax and putting my file data into `FormData` object solved my problem ~ ! I never thought of using `FormData` Could you explain further why it makes ajax work? and why my original code doesn't before?

Comment: Its better to not set the content type manually in ajax request to send the multipart data request as the boundary string will be missing in the request header and  the server knows where a parameter value starts and ends in case of multipart data request.

Comment: It did NOT worked for me, but this did `fd.append( "file", $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0])`