# Postman - Required MultipartFile parameter is not present - Spring, Java

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, multipartform-data, postman

**Edit**

This question is different from: [jQuery Ajax file upload : Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29488852/2279082)
The difference is that they use jQuery and Ajax, while I use a REST client - 'Postman'

So instead of setting Content-Type to false, I had to remove it altogether.

Also, when searching for answers about 'Postman', I believe people will skip questions that have the words jQuery and Ajax in them, this is what happened to me

**End Edit**

I'm using Spring MVC web application on Java8 and running it on tomcat7.x.
Spring version is: `4.2.6.RELEASE` and javax servlet version is: 3.0.1

**context.xml**

```
...

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5242880" /> <!-- 5MB -->

    <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->

</bean>

...
```

**controller.java**

```
...
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void importTranslations(@RequestParam (name = "myfile") MultipartFile myfile) {
    myService.doSomething(myfile);
}
...
```

**Here is the issue**

I use Postman to send a *.zip file. The path is correct and everything looks good, but spring throws an exception:
"Required MultipartFile parameter 'myfile' is not present"

**Here is the screenshot from Postman:**
[image]
So the file is there and the key name is correct.
Everything seems OK, and yet, I get the error

Comment: @Jens - Please see my edit at the beginning of the question, about possible duplication. It took me a while to find that answer and this is because I searched for Postman and dismissed answers about jQuery and Ajax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of searching here in stackoverflow, I found this question: [jQuery Ajax file upload : Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29488852/2279082)

I tried setting the Content-Type header in Postman to false and got an error.
When I removed the Content-Type header, it worked!!

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Saves my day.. great it worked.

Comment: @anil-prajapati - Glad to be able to help!