# Required String parameter 'file' is not present () when submitting data to my springboot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, file-upload, multipartform-data

In My controller, I have this method that receives data

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/takemyvid", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String upload2(@RequestParam("summary") String summary, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println(file);
    System.out.println(summary);
    return "";
}
```

However when I test it with postman with the correct parameters, I get an error

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'summary' is not present]
```

[image: Post Man Error]

This happens even when I only include the file.

I have setup the maximum file sizes in the properties file.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=128MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=128MB
```

Using Spring Boot version 2.1.2.RELEASE.

Comment: This has worked for just one string parameter, Kindly could you use my example to show me?

Comment: please post your request-headers (set in postman) as well. They will have influence on how Spring handles/converts the request parameters/body. See [Postman - Required MultipartFile parameter is not present - Spring, Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243908/postman-required-multipartfile-parameter-is-not-present-spring-java)

Comment: did you try my solution? did it work? @IsaacK

Comment: @Pijotrek, Thanks for the answer but the properties are null so logger line is throwing a null pointer exception.

Comment: Have you created the Dto class with getters and setters? Are you sure field names are equal to what you send in Postman? I tried my solution and it worked perfectly fine

Comment: Yes, thats the point, getters and setters are all there,

Comment: FileUploadDto [summary=null, file=null]

Comment: Please copy the code from: https://pastebin.com/k5f6S4wV  Maybe you messed up with imports or something? This is super strange...

Comment: Any progress maybe? @IsaacK

Comment: I gave up on it. I started with a different version of spring and my previous code worked. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `@ModelAttribute` annotation in the method arguments:

```
@RestController
public class UploadController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UploadController.class);

    @RequestMapping(path = "/takemyvid", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void upload2(@ModelAttribute FileUploadDto fileUploadDto) {
        logger.info("File uploaded, summary = {}, fileSize = {} bytes", fileUploadDto.getSummary(), fileUploadDto.getFile().getSize());
    }

}
```

And I also created the Dto class like this:

```
public class FileUploadDto {

    private String summary;
    private MultipartFile file;
    //getters, setters, whatevers [...]
}
```

This way it should work but you should consider better naming for your endpoints. `takemyvid` doesn't look quite right.

## edit

I just noticed you have some header set. If it's `Content-Type` set to Multipart, then please remove it because it may cause and Exception regarding multipart file boundary. Postman will handle it itself.

Comment: super advice! From a design point-of-view this **single DTO parameter** (helps in further processing) as well as **resource-oriented URL**-redesign (e.g. _POST_ to `/videos` or `/videos/uploads` - reveals endpoints' intention) both are strongly recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the advise guys, don't worry about the name of the endpoint for now, @Pijotrek, its throwing a null pointer exception while accessing object properties

Answer (score 0):

### Handling required VS optional request-parameters

The message `Required String parameter 'summary' is not present` reveals, that your `@RequestParam String summary` was by default `required = true` - see [java-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html#required--).

If you like to design the API-endpoint to have **summary** as **optional** then set `@RequestParam(required = false)`.

### Handling file-uploads

Since you are using a form (key-value-pairs), I would suggest to annotate the *file* parameter with `@RequestParam` and let Spring handle the conversion to specified parameter type `MultipartFile`.

See the [docs for @RequestPart](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html):

> Note that @RequestParam annotation can also be used to associate the part of a "multipart/form-data" request with a method argument supporting the same method argument types. The main difference is that when the method argument is not a String or raw MultipartFile / Part, @RequestParam relies on type conversion via a registered Converter or PropertyEditor while RequestPart relies on HttpMessageConverters taking into consideration the 'Content-Type' header of the request part. **RequestParam** is likely to be used with **name-value form fields** while **RequestPart** is likely to be used with parts containing more complex content e.g. **JSON, XML**).

See also Spring-Boot Docs, version 2.1.2, section 78.5 [Handling Multipart File Uploads](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration)