# Postman - Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present

Tags: java, spring, postman

I'm trying to call a post method with postman version 5.3.1 but I got the following error: "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present". I tried disabling the "Content-Type" Headers. I attached the file in the body section, selecting the form-data option and putting "file" on key input field.

I'm looking this post [jQuery Ajax file upload : Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29488852/jquery-ajax-file-upload-required-multipartfile-parameter-file-is-not-present) too but I cannot get a solution.

Comment: *"and putting the file key name"* - what does that mean? What is the `key` of the file you upload.

Comment: @luk2302 I edited the question, that means that I put "file" on the input field of the body/form-data section on postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer, I might be wrong if I am misunderstanding the issue.
In postman you should adjust the header as multipart/from-data, do this in order to upload a file using an endpoint.

This will be done here:

[image]

and here:

[image]

[image]

I really hope this helps, if not let me know, with more detail about the issue

===EDIT===

We are in a good path.
You are receiving a "The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found", and that is because your app need to split the "Multipart" being sent, and your application is complaining that it wasn't able to separate the data because it wasn't able to find its boundary, please read [rfc1341 - 7.2.1 Multipart: The common syntax](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html), where they explain about how boundairs work.

Now please try adding a boundary to the call. i.e.

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; 
          boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p
```

[image]

You will find the explanation on the documentation, on my test bed it worked, I hope this works for you (if not can you please provide the code example of you server endpoint).

Comment: If I do in this way I got: "The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"

Comment: Could you please try by removing the checkbox near the content type. and sending the request. I would like to force postman to set the multipart by itself.

For some reason the bondair is not set, when you set it by yourself.

Comment: I tried that. In the original post I put " I tried disabling the "Content-Type" Headers" but I got "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present"

Comment: I added some info about boundary, I hope it works. Please check after ===Edit===

Comment: Hi @moplin I putted the Content-Type like you show me, but I keep getting the message "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present". Following the code example of my endpoint: @RequestMapping(value = "/xxxxx/xxxxx/param1name/{param1}/... other params", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity<String> xxxxx(DTO dto, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile, @RequestHeader(value=HTTP_HEADER_CHECK_STATUS, required = false, defaultValue = "false") Boolean checkStatus)